# Boost.Asio socket destructor closes connection?

Tags: c++, sockets, boost, network-programming, boost-asio

What exactly does the destructor of `boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket` do? I can't tell, even after scouring Boost docs and source code, if I need to use

```
socket->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
socket->close();
```

before calling

```
delete socket;
```

Do I need to close the socket manually, or does the destructor handle this?

Comment: Looking at the [source code](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_57_0/boost/asio/basic_stream_socket.hpp)  it doesn't seem to have one.

Comment: I know. It's strange, since it seems like the socket would perform *some* cleanup, but I thought I just hadn't found the right piece of code.

Comment: No.  It must be the right code since it's straight from boost website unless some strange activity has been going on.  But the point is that there is no destructor so you have to shutdown and close the socket your self.  Understand?

Comment: @amanuel2 see my answer.

Comment: @amanuel2 All I/O objects defer their cleanup to the [`basic_io_object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object/_basic_io_object.html) from which they all derive.

Comment: You never need to call shutdown 'both' before closing unless you're dealing with a socket which has been inherited that you really really want to close now.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When a socket is destroyed, it will be closed *as-if* by [`socket.close(ec)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_socket/close/overload2.html) during the destruction of the socket.

I/O objects, such as `socket`, derive from [`basic_io_object`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object.html).  Within the [`basic_io_object` destructor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_io_object/_basic_io_object.html), `destroy()` will be invoked on the I/O object's I/O service, passing in an instance of the `implementation_type` on which the I/O object's service will operate.  In the case of socket, `destroy()` will be invoked on a type that fulfills the [SocketService](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/SocketService.html) type requirement, closing the underlying socket.  In the documentation below, `a` is an instance of a socket service class, and `b` is an instance of the `implementation_type` for the socket service class:

> `a.destroy(b)`:
>
> > [...] Implicitly cancels asynchronous operations, as if by calling `a.close(b, ec)`.
>
> `a.close(b, ec)`:
>
> > If `a.is_open()` is true, causes any outstanding asynchronous operations to complete as soon as possible. Handlers for cancelled operations shall be passed the error code `error::operation_aborted`.
> >
> > post: `!a.is_open(b)`.

Answer (score 4):

No you don't need to close it. Though it might be cleaner to do so, if you want to report any errors surrounding protocol shutdown.

The destructor just /appears/ to be empty, that's a good sign of Modern
 C++:

- http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three
- [Rule Of Zero](https://rmf.io/cxx11/rule-of-zero/)

Comment: Yes he has to manually close the socket connections manually. and implement the "Destructor" himself. nice answer.

Comment: @sehe - Does the destructor cleanly disconnect, performing the two calls in question? Or does it just abruptly close the connection?

Comment: @amanuel2 No, he doesn't have to manually close the socket connection *or* implement the destructor himself. Pointless comment.

Comment: @EJP yes he does have to manually close socket as so `socket->shutdown(boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket::shutdown_both);
socket->close();`

Comment: @amanuel, if you are observing that the socket's destructor does not close the underlying native socket, then please submit a bug report against Asio.  Per the documentation and implementation, the native socket should be closed during destruction of the socket.

Answer (score 4):

The answers have skipped over the issue of shutdown().  From the close() documentation, "For portable behaviour with respect to graceful closure of a connected socket, call shutdown() before closing the socket".

If deleting the socket does an implicit close, it seems that a call to shutdown() is still recommended before deleting it.