# Tcp proxy mysql.The data received from the mysql-client is output in weird symbols

Tags: c++, mysql, string, proxy, boost-asio

```
// std:string _sql_statement;
// char _client_data[max_data_length];
// size_t bytes_transferred;

void tcp_proxy::Bridge::handle_read_fclient(const error_code& error, const size_t & bytes_transferred)
{

    if (!error) {
        
        asio::async_write(*_upstream_socket.get(),
            asio::buffer(_client_data, bytes_transferred),
            boost::bind(&Bridge::handle_write_tserver,
                shared_from_this(),
                asio::placeholders::error)
        );
        
        _sql_statement.append(_client_data, bytes_transferred);
        std::cout << _sql_statement << "\n";
    }
    else {
        stop();
    }
}
```

When i run mysql-client and send sql query, i get this output:

```
����=9漢     �\�gOx� �u%e��A ��
��jxt�6����                               �bc ���z�
           �-x��w<�0NH�+�,�/�#�'�0�$�(��g@�kj���        ��
23895�A��<=/��

*(

+-3GEA1�����Ȩf� ��b�_�Epx����D�47�~�;%/x��C)�Q���D3     ���n�]�B�brU�N�ݘ%_\�
                                                                            7F�e����
                                                                                    u��ED�Ϳ�T�Q����XyȀt�xb8��� ����������'�Zm�V엇DT��!»
                                                                                                                                       ����@��2��     Nd۠;��̭�1�t5QtU�M�`�B�<�վmwX[�
�0�5���]��yM!��}/E��|g$�&���8�&~�a?C��_���z��տ�ɝN�D�Ǉ0�z����|�v,�r�$]���*HJ�$'��xGQ)P�4��TI�=8qc?���)`��N?_U率`���K��U4��8f���  &�
```

I tried using printf, but it didn't work. I will be glad of any hint, a link to the literature.

Comment: You don't receive anything in the code-snippet you show. You *send*. And you send *asynchronously* which means the actual data might not have been sent when the `async_write` function returns. Same with `async_read`, nothing might have been actually received when the function returns.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude. I am trying to write a proxy server that would communicate with the database and log all requests. I connect to the proxy as follows: mysql -u root -p -h "ip_proxy" -P "port_proxy". When sending standard queries, such as "show databases;" I get the correct response in the mysql-client console. I am trying to display the request when writing data from the client to the server (in the database).  Please tell me if the logic is built correctly?

Comment: You clearly have something not built correctly.  It would help to see the proxy code.

Comment: @sehe. [You can see the code in my gitlab](https://gitlab.com/v-danis/tcp-proxy)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is working. Mysql protocol isn't text-based. Printing it as-if it were text is inappropriate. Instead, consider hex-dumping like e.g.:

```
_sql_statement.assign(_client_data, bytes_transferred);

std::cout << "Received " << bytes_transferred << " bytes: ";
{
    std::ostream hex(std::cout.rdbuf());
    hex << std::hex << std::showbase << std::setfill('0');
    for (auto i = 0; i < bytes_transferred; ++i) {
        uint8_t octet = _client_data[i];
        hex << " " << std::setw(4) << static_cast<int>(octet);
    }
}
std::cout << std::endl;
```

> Note I also changed `append` into `assign` to avoid infinite growth. Also consider renaming `_sql_statemtent` into `_data` to avoid misleading names.

### Review Notes

A few things:

- the mutex is useless if only one spot ever locks it
- to avoid issues, don't `close()` during potential async operations. Instead `cancel()` them and let the error handling clean up via `shared_from_this()`
- same for the acceptor, just setting `_stopped = true` doesn't force the pending accept to complete. Instead, cancel() the `_acceptor`.
- Don't abuse `shared_ptr::get()`, `atomic<T>::load()` and `atomic<T>::store()` for no reason
- avoid the code duplication around async read:

  ```
   void tcp_proxy::Bridge::handle_connection(error_code const& error) {
       if (!error) {
           do_read_fserver();
           do_read_fclient();
       } else {
           std::cerr << "Connect Error! Error code = " << error.value() << ". Message : " << error.message() << "\n";
           stop();
       }
   }
  ```

  and re-use the same `do_read_fXXX()` function in the write completions.
- handle EOF properly. It's possible to have received data when EOF is encountered. So, write the data to the other end destroying the connection:

  ```
  if (!error || error == asio::error::eof) {
  ```

  I'll leave it as an exercise to the reader to optionally keep track of shutdown states (see e.g. [boost::asio cleanly disconnecting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1993216/boostasio-cleanly-disconnecting/3068106#3068106))
- you call `proxy.stop_proxy()` after ... `ios.run()` completed. That's useless by definition. Consider just omitting it, or put it in a more useful spot (e.g. in a `signal_set::async_wait` handler?)

### Demo

I also created a branch with these review comments on Gitlab: https://gitlab.com/v-danis/tcp-proxy/-/merge_requests/1 (branch https://gitlab.com/bitbucket54/tcp-proxy/-/tree/sehe-review?ref_type=heads).

Local demo:[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! I will definitely read more about your comments.  As you can see, this area of programming is new to me.  Do you have any literature that you could recommend for beginners?

Comment: Not really. I learned it on here as well, and just using Boost examples. A lot of my understanding was attained the hard way: by writing demo programs to test my assumptions and by reading the actual library code to verify them.

Comment: Updated code with improvements (DNS resolution, less duplication, error/eof/close handling) in [new answer with code and explanations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77443747/85371). Also pushed to that old branch https://gitlab.com/bitbucket54/tcp-proxy/-/tree/sehe-review - removing all the unneeded cruft