# How to read till end of data on tcp socket when data is SSL with boost asio

Tags: c++, ssl, boost, proxy

First of all, I am new in c++ and please pay attention that maybe I am doing wrong from the first step and my problem will not be resloved by writing codes differently. I will try to describe what I am doing

I am trying to write a proxy server with c++ using boost asio which has two parts

- **Agent** : is responsible to get requests from client and transfer it to server
- **Server** : is responsible to get requests from agent and send it to origin server

My purpose is to write something which break the internet filtering. It works fine for HTTP requests but in HTTPS i face with issue.

Note: The requests from agent  to server is normal HTTP POST request with body and the response from server is normal 200 OK with body

Flow of one requests

**Client** ----over_https_proxy----> **Agent** ----ENCODED_AND_SEND_HTTP_POST_WITH_BODY----> **Server** ----DECODE_AND_SEND_ORIGINAL_REQUEST_TO_ORIGINAL_SERVER----> **Origin**

Flow of the response

**Origin** ----RESPONSE_OF_ORIGINAL_REQUEST----> **Server** ----ENCODE_ORIGINAL_RESPONSE_200_OK_WITH_BODY----> **Agent** ----DECODE_BODY_AND_SEND_RESPONSE----> **Client**

1. Server and Agent are running and listening on port over tcp
2. Client set http and https proxy to IP and Port of Agent like `http_proxy="http://agent:8080"`
3. Client call a https url like `curl https://www.google.com -v`
4. Client sends connect request to Agent
5. Agent gets connect request and encode it by base64 and put it to body of simple post request and send it to Server
6. Server gets the post request and decode the body and parse the connect request and open a socket to the destination (origin server) and checks if the destination is available or not and send response to agent
7. Agent recieve the response from server and send it to client for example `HTTP/1.1 200 Connection established` if socket from server
8. Client get the response and start to SSL handshake
9. Client starts the handshake
10. and My problem starts here

At first I tried to read with methods like

```cpp
boost::asio::read_until(
            socket_,
            readBuffer_,
            "\r\n",
            error
        );
```

But ssl is not like http or ftp end with "\r\n" or "\r\n\r\n"

I tried with

```cpp
boost::asio::read(
        socket_,
        readBuffer_,
        boost::asio::transfer_at_least(1),
        error
        );
```

But it gets part of requests and not all of it for example it gets part of client hello or all server hello and not cipher change request
I even tried with `boost::asio::transfer_all()` but in this case it waits for EOF but I got the feeling that the EOF will be detected only if the connection is terminated and it depends on the beheviour of connection endpoints. For example google.com may wait only 10 seconds to get any data on session if not it will drop it and EOF will be transmited to other peer which it is not the case.

Or like following in a while loop byte by byte till EOF

```cpp
while (
    boost::asio::read(
        socket_,
        readBuffer_,
        boost::asio::transfer_exactly(1),
        error
        )
)
{
  /*
    check for error and handler
  */
}
```

In this case it reads all data but it waits for long time to make sure that there is no more data. In this case I don't know how should I tell not to wait???

Please pay attention that in each case I always took care of EndOfFile(EOF) handling.

Then the idea came to my mind to read byte by byte from socket and parse the byte and detect the ssl transmission steps and the bytes followed by parsing header record. You can see detail of steps for example **[here](https://tls12.xargs.org/#client-key-exchange/annotated)**
But it was so difficult to detect all cases correctly. Imagine this case that the response is only application data which starts with "17" and you can not expect how many application data responses will you get. or even the handshake steps are sometimes in different ways some of them are done by server hello done but some of them not

**UPDATE**:

My problem is not reading between Agent and Server since I am able to handle because all request are generated by myself, and I am controlling requests between them. My problem is reading from Client on Agent side and reading from Origin on Server side, which is not me and could be anything. I can not detect end of data over socket when the connection is SSL

I prepared a code to simulate what I am testing. It will listen on tcp/127.0.0.10:8080

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/bind/bind.hpp>

class TCPConnection
    : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<TCPConnection>
{
public:
    using pointer =  boost::shared_ptr<TCPConnection>;

    static pointer create(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
    {
        return pointer(new TCPConnection(io_context));
    }

    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket& socket()
    {
        return socket_;
    }

    void start()
    {
        std::cout << "start" << std::endl;
        doRead();
    }

    void doRead()
    {
        std::cout << "doRead" << std::endl;
        while(true){
            boost::system::error_code error;
            auto size = boost::asio::read(
                socket_,
                readBuffer_,
                boost::asio::transfer_exactly(1),
                error
            );
            std::cout << size << std::endl;
            if (error == boost::asio::error::eof || size == 0)
                break;
            else if (error)
            {
                std::cout << "ERROR" << error.what() << std::endl;
            }
        }
      std::cout << "END" << std::endl;
    }
    
private:
    explicit TCPConnection(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
        : socket_(io_context)
    { }
    
    boost::asio::ip::tcp::socket socket_;
    boost::asio::streambuf readBuffer_, writeBuffer_;
};

class TCPServer 
{
public:
    using pointer =  boost::shared_ptr<TCPServer>;

    static pointer create(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
    {
        return pointer(new TCPServer(io_context));
    }

private:
    explicit TCPServer(boost::asio::io_context& io_context)
        : io_context_(io_context),
            acceptor_(
                io_context,
                boost::asio::ip::tcp::endpoint(
                    boost::asio::ip::address::from_string("127.0.0.10"),
                    8080
                )
            )
    {
        startAccept();
    }

    void startAccept()
    {
        std::cout << "startAccept" << std::endl;

        TCPConnection::pointer newConnection =
            TCPConnection::create(io_context_);
        
        acceptor_.async_accept(newConnection->socket(),
            boost::bind(&TCPServer::handleAccept, 
                this, 
                newConnection,
                boost::asio::placeholders::error)
            );
    }

    void handleAccept(TCPConnection::pointer newConnection,
        const boost::system::error_code& error)
    {
        if (!error)
        {
            boost::asio::socket_base::keep_alive option(true);
            newConnection->socket().set_option(option);
            newConnection->start();
        }
        startAccept();
    }
    
        boost::asio::io_context& io_context_;
        boost::asio::ip::tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    boost::asio::io_context io_context_;
    TCPServer::pointer tcpServer_ = TCPServer::create(io_context_);
    io_context_.run();
}
```

Then simply set the http_proxy

```bash
export https_proxy="http://127.0.0.10:8080"
```

and try to curl somewhere

```bash
curl https://www.google.com
```

My expectation is to see END in output of c++ code but you will never see it till you kill your curl command

**END OF UPDATE**

So my questions are

1. Am I doing the correct thing from base? I mean is it possible at all to read till end of data without parsing the ssl streams byte by byte?
2. How the other applications handle SSL requests? for example how nginx detects and handles it?
3. Is boost proper tool for what I want to do or should I handle stuff with Basic c++ libraries?

Thanks a lot for your attention and helping me

## Solution

I will try to update here if I got any solution for thist issue

I found one abbility from socket which was helpfull
In sample code above I was able to read till data available with checking the **socket_.available()** it will be zero if there is no more data available in socket. So i need to check it after each byte that I read from socket

```cpp
if (error == boost::asio::error::eof || size == 0 || socket_.available() == 0)
  break;
```

But this solution is not reliable
It seems the only way is to pars the stream and read till end bytes, which I can find it in ssl header record

Comment: You need two threads, one in each direction. Both threads should read until end of stream and write everything they read to the other side. When one thread encounters EOS it should shutdown the other end for output. When both ends have been shutdown for output both ends can be closed.

Comment: @user207421
Thanks for the hint. But I can not detect where is the end of the stream. If I was able to find something as end of stream, my problem was resolved. As I mentioned end of stream in HTTP or FTP is "\r\n" but in case of HTTPS (SSL) it is not clear and there is nothing as end of stream on socket. On the other hand, this is request and response client sends the request and waits for the response and I MUST do this in correct sequence synchronously.

Comment: End of stream is signaled by  `read()` or `recv()` returning zero. No mystery. And you don’t have to do this synchronously. The point of the two threads is that it removes the need to understand the protocol. Once you get past the connect phase you’re just shoveling bytes in both directions simultaneously. So for example HTTP keepalive, where there is more than one request in the input, just works, without you having to parse the request, or decrypt it in the case of HTTPS. This is how  proxying is done.

Comment: I've recently answered some very related questions about proxy-server implementations with asio, you might find them useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77443747/85371, https://stackoverflow.com/a/77062618/85371,  https://stackoverflow.com/a/77863203/85371,

Comment: @user207421Thanks a lot. But I want to encode the origin request to bypass the filtering. Imagine YouTube is filtered and the filtering system detect and filter it by SNI during SSL handshake and drop the connection in the middle. I want to hide original requests which contain the SNI into a simple HTTP POST request. I can not just forward bytes between Agent and Server.

Comment: @user207421 About End of Stream I tried to read byte by byte. Actually it reads till end of the all bytes on socket and it is fine. But after I read the last byte from socket for the next byte (which is empty and nothing on socket) with read method it waits for long time and I do not know how should I handle this part. For example, there are 512 bytes on socket from Client to Agent, I can read all 512 bytes in a while loop till the read is zero but in this case for byte number 513 it waits for long time. Could you please help me to find how can i fix it?

Comment: Eh? End of stream means that the peer has closed the connection. It doesn’t mean end of message. You get zero at end of stream. After that there is no more data and you will get zero again, immediately. Your question doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @user207421 Exactly my problem is that I do not get zero immediately. Trust me or not, this is my issue that I do not get zero by boost::asio::read() immediately.

Comment: @user207421 But in my case the connection is still alive and no one closes the connection since the SSL handshake is not over yet.

Comment: @user207421 I have added a simple code to update the section of the post to simulate what I am talking about. You can test and see that It will not return zero immediately. And you will see END only when you kill your curl command (which is EOF).

Comment: I agree, It will return zero at end of *stream*, and not before. 'End of *data*' is ill-defined. It you mean 'end of *message,*', you have to parse the message, or else rely rather poorly on a read timeout.

Comment: `available()` only tells you whether there is data available to be read *without blocking,* i.e. *now*. It is not a reliable indicator of end of message. The only way you can get that is via *parsing the message.*

Comment: @user207421 Thanks a lot for your hint. I will try to fix it by parsing the message

Answer (score 0):

If everything is HTTP, is there any reason why you're not using `curl` everywhere, rather than using `asio` and then trying to parse the http yourself? `curl` should handle all of these details for you.

If you're using a custom protocol, say between the server and the agent, and designing this protocol yourself, the usual solution is to define each message to start with a fixed length integer (say four bytes), with the number of bytes in the message. On the receiving end, you read the integer, then read the number of bytes it indicates. There are obviously other solutions, but this seems to be the simplest.

FWIW: HTTP (like SMTP and NNTP) were designed with the idea that the TCP connection would be closed after each message, so the reading process just read the entire stream into memory, and parsed it there. HTTP now supports keeping the TCP connection open, but I don't really know how this is implemented; the only immediate solution I see is to read byte by byte until you have to entire header, and go on from there. But there are readily available libraries, like `curl`, which have solved this problem, so you don't have to.

UPDATE:

After having posted this, I actually remembered having solved a similar problem some years ago. The protocol in question wasn't HTTP, the the principle is the same. The trick is to use the `read_some` member function (present in both `asio::ip::tcp::socket` and `asio::ssl::stream`). Basically, allocate a relatively large buffer (we used 32K), then continuously do `read_some`, appending to the buffer, until you find the empty line (`"\x0d\x0a\x0d\x0a"`). At this point, the buffer contains the entire header (and maybe more). Then, depending on the message type:

- The message has no content (a `GET`, for example). In this case, you
  have the complete message.
- The message has content, but no `Content-Length` field. In this case,
  you can read to end of file: if the peer entity sends a message with
  content, but without a `Content-Length` field, it is required
  terminate the TCP connection (close the socket) at the end of the
  message.
- The message has content, and a `Content-Length` field. You know how
  many bytes of content you've already read, so you subtract this from
  the length in the `Content-Length` field, and read that many bytes.

In theory, each `read_some` may return just a single byte, so you would be doing a byte-by-byte read; in practice, the peer entity will be sending packets, and each `read_some` will return an entire packet.

One last word of warning: `read_some` will block until it can return at least one byte (or the connection has terminated). Be careful to not call it after you've read the empty line until you have determined that there is still more content to read.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer
About the "If everything is HTTP", Everything between Agent and server is HTTP but between Client and Agent or Server and Origin No it is not always HTTP and could be HTTP or HTTPS.
My problem is not reading between Agent and Server since I am able to handle because all request are generated by myself, and I am controlling requests between them.
My problem is reading from Client and Origin, which is not me and could be anything. I can not detect end of data over socket when the connection is SSL. I hope my description is helpful at this comment